# How Doorkeeper implements refreshing a token for PKCE client

Tags: oauth-2.0, doorkeeper, appauth, pkce

I'm using the newest version of Doorkeeper (which is a wonderful gem) and enabled PKCE. It works great for authorization flow (I use authorization_code). However, when I'm trying to refresh token later I'm getting 401.

Params

```
{"refresh_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "scope"=>"xxx", 
"redirect_uri"=>"com.example://callback", 
"client_id"=>"xxx", "grant_type"=>"refresh_token"}
```

The client is a mobile app using AppAuth which as can you see above doesn't send `code_challange` when refreshing a token. As we read [here](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/178) creators of PKCE says that server should allow for refreshing token without sending code challenge again. **How the gem implements that?**